# MySQL three table join

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have three tables

Table1

```
userid  mobile
1       123456789
2       321654987
3       987456321
```

Table2

```
revid   userid  revdes  mobile
1       2       ASD     123456789
2       2       DSA     123456348
3       1       QWE     963258124
```

Table3

```
revid   revloc
1       asdf
3       dsaq
```

I want output like this where userid=2

```
userid  revid    revdes     mobile      revloc  inTable1
2       1        ASD        123456789   asdf    true
2       2        DSA        123456348   NULL    false
```

**In the above output inTable1 column 1st row element is true because mobile "123456789" is available on Table1**

I am using MySQL.

Comment: How are you fetching the `mobile` column value in the "above output". What is the logic?

Comment: @SarathChandra in output mobile column values come from table2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you want using a series of left joins.  The tricky part with your query was knowing to join `Table1` and `Table2` using the mobile number, rather than the user id.

```
SELECT t2.userid, t2.revid, t2.revdes, t2.mobile, t3.revloc,
    t1.mobile IS NOT NULL AS inTable1
FROM Table2 t2 LEFT JOIN Table1 t1
    ON t2.mobile = t1.mobile
LEFT JOIN Table3 t3
      ON t2.revid = t3.revid
WHERE t2.userid = 2
```

**Follow the link below for a running demo:**

## SQLFiddle

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `left join` and just check if the resulting column is `null` or not:

```
SELECT    t2.userid, t2.revid, t2.revdes, t2.mobile, t3.revloc, 
          t1.mobile IS NOT NULL AS inTable1
FROM      table2 t2
JOIN      table3 t3 ON t2.revid = t3.revid
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t2.mobile = t1.mobile
```

Comment: This query has some problems (I didn't downvote you).

Comment: inTable1 is true when t1.mobile IS NOT NULL. Please fix the SELECT part. The rest seems correct to me, apart from the fact that, by doing so, t1.mobile is 1 or 0, not 'true' or 'false' as requested.

Comment: @LucaCalabrese Yup typing faster than I think. Fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query hope it helps:

```
SELECT Table1.userid, Table2.revid, Table2.revdes, Table2.mobile, Table3.revloc, IF(Table1.mobile = Table2.mobile, true, false) as inTable1
FROM Table1 
JOIN Table2 ON Table2.userid = Table1.userid 
JOIN Table3 ON Table2.revid = Table3.revid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t2.userid, t2.revid, t2.revdes, t2.mobile, t3.revloc,
    CASE WHEN (SELECT t4.mobile from Table1 t4 where t4.userid = T2.userid) = T2.mobile
    THEN true ELSE false END AS inTable1
FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2, Table3 t3
WHERE (t2.userid = t1.userid) AND (t2.revid = t3.revid)
```